# Parse the List of objects in AWS Connect

Tags: aws-lambda

AWS lambda returns the below List. How can I parse the List in AWS Connect?
In AWS Connect, if lambda returns a single attribute (customerId) I can parse that value in
Connect using $.External.customerId and was able to play that CustomerId.

If Lamda returns the below List, I was accessing in connect as: $.External.list.CustomerId
and it fails. No errors n Cloudwatch Logs. Any idea how to parse the below list in Connect?

AWS lambda returns the below List. How can I parse the List in AWS Connect?
In AWS Connect, if lambda returns a single attribute (customerId) I can parse that value in
Connect using $.External.customerId and was able to play that CustomerId.

If Lamda returns the below List, I was accessing in connect as: $.External.list.CustomerId
and it fails. No errors n Cloudwatch Logs. Any idea how to parse the below list in Connect?

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "CustomerId": 224455,
      "CustName": "John"
    },
    {
      "CustomerId": 334455,
      "CustName": "Peter"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "list": [
    {
      "CustomerId": 224455,
      "CustName": "John"
    },
    {
      "CustomerId": 334455,
      "CustName": "Peter"
    }
  ]
}
```

I should be able to parse in Connect as: $.External.list.customerId
and $.External.list.custName

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the index for the element you are accessing in the list.

`$.External.list[0].customerId`

This is using JSONPaths
https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html

Comment: Thank you Geeshan. I did tried with:  $.External.list[0].CustomerId and is not working?
Please suggest if there is any other way of doing? I think Connect cannot parse the list?